# Detecção de sorrisos utilizando opencv no android

Tags: java, android, opencv

Olá, estou tendo dificuldades para fazer a detecção de sorrisos utilizando opencv no android. Consigo fazer a detecção de faces e olhos muito bem utilizando haar cascade porém apenas a detecção dos sorrisos não está dando certo utilizando esse método.

```
private Mat image, originalImage, imgGray;
private CascadeClassifier face;
private CascadeClassifier eye; //atributos
private CascadeClassifier smile;
private Size dsize = new Size(480, 640);
private MatOfRect faceDetections;
private MatOfRect eyeDetections;
private MatOfRect smileDetections;
private boolean center;

public FaceDetection(Mat imagem, Mat imgCinza) {
    //load the haarcascade's archives to detect faces, eyes and smiles.

    this.face = new CascadeClassifier("/storage/emulated/0/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    this.face.load("/storage/emulated/0/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    this.eye = new CascadeClassifier("/storage/emulated/0/data/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml");
    this.eye.load("/storage/emulated/0/data/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml");
    this.smile = new CascadeClassifier("/storage/emulated/0/data/haarcascade_myhaar.xml");
    this.smile.load("/storage/emulated/0/data/haarcascade_myhaar.xml");
    this.originalImage = imagem;
    this.imgGray = new Mat();
    this.image = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(imgCinza, this.imgGray, dsize);
    Imgproc.resize(this.originalImage, this.image, dsize);
    this.faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    this.eyeDetections = new MatOfRect();
    this.smileDetections = new MatOfRect();
}

public void detectate() {
    eye.detectMultiScale(imgGray, eyeDetections);
    smile.detectMultiScale(imgGray, smileDetections);
    face.detectMultiScale(imgGray, faceDetections);
    faceDetect();
    System.out.println("Funcionou");
}
```

Como mostrado no código, estou carregando os cascades passando o caminho dos arquivos xml dos haarcascades. A minha dúvida é porque apenas a detecção de faces e olhos funciona, sendo que estou utilizando um haarcascade do próprio opencv para a detectção de sorrisos e apenas esse não funciona. Espero ter deixado mais claro a minha dificuldade.

Comment: Quais dificuldades? Vc não indica quais são, e assim fica difícil alguém te ajudar. Veja que este site *não é* um fórum, e sim um site de perguntas e respostas. Faça o [tour], leia [ask], depois volte aqui e edite sua pergunta para melhorá-la. Explique o que acontece de errado e forneça exemplos do seu código.

Comment: haar e cascade até onde sei são apenas para detecção de faces, não exatamente identificar sorrisos, talvez precise de outras características

Comment: Vi que vc adicionou o código. Muito bem. Só que ainda não está claro o seguinte: vc usa vários cascades, um para detectar faces frontais (`haarcascade_frontalface_alt`), um para detectar olhos com ou sem óculos (`haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses`), e um que parece customizado, isto é, feito por vc e não padrão do OpenCV (`haarcascade_myhaar`). É esse que deveria detectar sorrisos? Se sim e não está funcionando, o problema está no seu treinamento. Vc usou imagens apenas com sorrisos (positivas) e de qualquer outra coisa, isto é, sem sorrisos (negativas)? Adicione detalhes que eu voto pra abrir.

Comment: @AndréCarvalho Na verdade esse algoritmo é bom em detectar qualquer coisa que possa ser exemplificada em imagens. [Até mesmo bananas](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html). :) O problema é que ele não é muito robusto a variações que fujam das imagens usadas no treinamento.

Comment: No momento que o algoritmo conseguir identificar o sorriso da Monalisa (usado como controle, sem estar no treinamento), vou dizer que ele é bom

Comment: Então, esse haarcascade foi feito por mim após testar os que já vem no próprio opencv que não funcionaram. E sim, no treinamento utilizei como imagens positivas apenas imagens com sorrisos e como imagens negativas imagens de qualquer outras coisas. Utilizei esse vídeo como base para criar o meu haarcascade. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dg-4MoABv4I